# Getting an error while deploying the Target Android Version 12 App

Tags: xamarin.forms, deployment

After upgrading the Target Android Version to 12, I'm not able to deploy my App and I get the below error:

> Error     ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1678539237.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #23): crc64045f0433dcf30634.FirebaseNotificationService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Here is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="testapp.com" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="31" android:versionName="4.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="Test App" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:allowBackup="false">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How can I fix this issue? Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, there is a service named `FirebaseNotificationService` in your project didn't declare the `exported` property.

If you used some nuget packages about the firebase, you can try to update the nuget package to the newest version.

If the `FirebaseNotificationService` is created by yourself, you need to declare the `exported` property for it.